# Alternative wording for 'pre filled' for Partially filled out PDF printout forms

Tags: wording, content-management

This is more of a wording/content strategy issue than anything:

But we have developed some on-line forms for our customers to fill out, however the top portion of the form (5 or so fields) are pre-filled with the unit number and the customer name, kind of acting as a little time saver.

However the term 'pre-filled' insinuates the entire form is filled out automatically with nothing to add, So really looking for some terminology that would imply that only the top portion is filled out.

A couple of screenshots attached for clarity.

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I, personally, would remove **pre-filled** altogether, as it isn't really necessary to know that the form is partially filled out for you.  That's kind of obvious when you click the link and see it filled out.  In your example, there doesn't seem to be much data that's filled out for you anyway.  I could see the benefit of wanting to say something if most of the form was filled out, but in this case, I'd just leave it off.

That said, if you really want something there, you could say something like:

- **Field Data Input Sheets** *(Partially filled)*
- **Field Data Input Sheets** *(Partly filled)*
- **Field Data Input Sheets** *(Top portion autofilled)*
- **Field Data Input Sheets** *(Top portion prefilled)*
- **Field Data Input Sheets** *(Top portion autocompleted)*
- **Field Data Input Sheets** *(Top section autofilled)*
- **Field Data Input Sheets** *(Top section prefilled)*
- **Field Data Input Sheets** *(Top section autocompleted)*
- **Field Data Input Sheets** *(Some data autofilled)*
- **Field Data Input Sheets** *(Some data prefilled)*
- **Field Data Input Sheets** *(Some data autocompleted)*

---

Just as an addendum, you can take a look at the **English Language & Usage** accepted answer  for the following question I posted:

### *[What's the most preferred spelling of auto fill, auto-fill, and autofill?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/146660/60050)*

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's easier to make the following distinctions

- Blank forms
- "Company Name": "Unit Name" Forms

I don't know if users have to be logged in to see these forms, but if they were then you could possibly only show them the blank forms and the forms specific to their company (based on profile or email info).

Comment: Just to elaborate a little bit further, but the drop down label would be "blank forms" and then list all of the forms underneath that. And then have another drop down for "Customer Name" and list all of the forms with "Unit" names as labels.

Answer (score 0):

Using the phrase 'populated' may be appropriate here.  The forms are 'populated' with data already, so forth.